# Drawer menu performances

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm developing a side menu for my web-application (in the mobile version) using Angular2.

This the class when the menu is closed

```
.main-drawer
{
    left: -300px;
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition-property: left;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

When the user press the open-menu button I add the following class using jQuery

```
.main-drawer.opened
{
    left:0;
    transition-property: left;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

This is the js code:

```
let drawer = jQuery ('.main-drawer');
drawer.toggleClass ('opened', !drawer.hasClass ('opened'));
```

Using this code on desktop computers the performances are good, but on mobile version it is laggy.
Is there a way to increase per performance?

The menu is pretty lightweight, does not contain a lot of nodes.
I noticed that other websites have pretty good performances even if their menu is full of things.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating `x`/`y` is more performant than transitioning or animation `top`/`left`, because translation leans on the GPU for rendering, which is powerful and makes movement smooth. `top` and `left` are operating at a DOM level, which is restrictive.

Also, you can shorten things a little. You can define your transition in one place on your initial element and then just define only what's changing in the added class. Try this:

```
.main-drawer
{
    transform: translateX(-300px);
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 300ms transform ease-out;
}

.main-drawer.opened
{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, it works like a sharm!!
Do you have other tips like this?
Thank you again

Comment: Here's a good read for you: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/. Also Google about for Paul Irish and web performance.